# How do I create a project in Visual Studio not meant to compile?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, project, projects-and-solutions

I've got a Visual Studio 2010 solution that I would like to add a project to that only contains some command-line scripts.  This project isn't meant to actually compile/build anything, but I want to be able to edit my scripts with the rest of the solution, and have TFS integration etc.

Unfortunately, in searching I get a lot of results for errors where builds don't happen, or other conditions where specific build targets are implemented.  I simply want a non-build project in VS as a visual repository for the editor.  I don't want to one-by-one include individual files in a solution folder.

Answer (score 2):

In the [build configuration manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t1hy4dhz%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (On the Menu, "Build", "Configuration Manager"), there is a "build" checkbox for each project.  Uncheck it for your script project.

Answer (score 0):

Could you make a content project, add your scripts to it, then change their properties to "Do not compile"?

Comment: Right now, I do this with a web project (not web app)... which is as close as I can get.